# Cannot produce events to Confluent Kafka deployed on AWS EC2 from local machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I'm trying to connect from an external client (my laptop) to a broker in a Kafka cluster that I have running on ec2 machines. When I try and connect from my local machine I get the following error:

```
$ ./kafka-console-producer --broker-list AWS.PRIV.ATE.IP:9092 --topic test
>hi
>[2018-09-20 13:28:53,952] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-0: 1519 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

The topic exists because if I run (from local machine)

```
$ ./kafka-topics --list --zookeeper AWS.PRIV.ATE.IP:2181
__confluent.support.metrics
__consumer_offsets
_schemas
connect-configs
connect-offsets
connect-status
test
```

The cluster configuration is from Confluent's AWS quickstart template: https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-confluent-kafka/blob/master/templates/confluent-kafka.template and I'm running the open source version.

The three broker ec2 instances are visible to my local machine, which I verified by stopping the Kafka broker, starting a simple HTTP server on port 9092, and successfully `curl`ing that server using the internal IP address of the ec2 instance.

If I `ssh` into one of the broker instances I can successfully produce and consume messages across the cluster. The only update I've made to the out-of-the-box configuration provided by the template is changing `listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-AWS-PUB-LIC-IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092` in `server.properties` on each machine and then restarted the kafka server.

I can provide more configuration or debugging info if necessary. Believe the issue is something regarding IP address discoverability/visibility but I'm not entirely sure what.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `advertised.listeners` too.

See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ for details.